# GetClassName from SHELLEXECUTEINFO

Tags: c#, c

I am launching firefox with the ShellExecuteEx function. Does the SHELLEXECUTEINFO hwnd then contain a window handle? it seems not. because getlasterror returns error when trying to GetClassName.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

HWND of SHELLEXECUTEINFO should be provided by you to be the parent of any dialog box (as MessageBox). it is not the handle of the main window of the application you want to start.

Comment: Thanks. I want to put some text into an edit box.in firefox. Any ideas how?

Comment: browsers do not have edit boxes neither buttons as regular. these are just drawings (windowless controls). you better deal with HTML objects, but these are not that easy task. do google for a tutorial.

Comment: Thanks. Not exactly an edit box. dlgitem maybe. One of those fields for entering username and passwords.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. So no luck without HTML knowledge?

Comment: that is not that hard. you can learn it in just few days. and it worth. check tutorials and practice.

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer.